# main program that receives arguments, recognizes chars, and verifies if one argument is present

Tags: arrays, c, string, char, arguments

I'm very new to programming and aI would say almost mediocre. I have a program I need to write for school and the First requirements are :

1. main program must be able to receive a variable amount of arguments from terminal. If no argument is given, program must stop.
2. main program can recognize the arguments/options "-t,-c,-a,-g" (in no particular order).
3. main program must make sure that argument -t is present. if it's not, program must stop and print a message asking to provide at least one title (-t is for title).

Here is what I have so far for only the first requirement.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void reception_critere(int argc, char * argv[]); //declaration of fct

void reception_critere(int argc, char * argv[]) //definition of fct
  {
    int i;
    // affichage des arguments
printf("Nombre d’arguments passes au programme : %d\n", argc);
    for(i = 0 ; i< argc ; i ++) {
       printf("   argv[%d] : ‘%s’\n", i, argv[i]);
  }


  //prg.c
  int main (void) 
  {

    reception_critere() //not sure what to put here
    return 0 ; 

  }
```

Comment: What does your books or tutorials say about the `argc` and `argv` arguments? Which function should actually have those arguments?

Comment: @sarras It is the function main that must be declared with arguments int main ( int argc, char * argv[] )

Answer (score 1):

They must already be received from the main function.
like this :

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    reception_critere(argc, argv); 
    return 0 ;
}
```